# What is the difference between Precipitated Calcium Carbonate and Calcium Carbonate?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I don't know what  [precipitated calcium carbonate](http://www.acpl.co/) is. So anybody who knows the answer let me know.

Comment: There's a chemical process involved that they'll probably explain  better on [chemistry](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about learning chemistry, not English

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_carbonate) documents two methods to obtain or prepare calcium carbonate used in industry: mining (or quarrying) and preparing **PCC** (**precipitated calcium carbonate**) from calcium oxide.

> The vast majority of calcium carbonate used in industry is extracted by mining or quarrying. Pure calcium carbonate (e.g. for food or pharmaceutical use), can be produced from a pure quarried source (usually marble).
>   
>   Alternatively, calcium carbonate is prepared from calcium oxide. Water is added to give calcium hydroxide, and carbon dioxide is passed through this solution to precipitate the desired calcium carbonate, referred to in the industry as precipitated calcium carbonate (PCC):
>   
>   ​　　　CaCO<sub>3</sub> → CaO + CO<sub>2</sub>
>   ​　　　CaO + H<sub>2</sub>O → Ca(OH)<sub>2</sub>
>   ​　　　Ca(OH)<sub>2</sub> + CO<sub>2</sub> → CaCO<sub>3</sub> + H<sub>2</sub>O
>   
>   <sup>Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_carbonate</sup>

Thus, the "precipitated calcium carbonate" in your question is made (prepared) by such a process, from calcium oxide.